# How to Fade-out Gtranslate WP Plugin Language Selection Button On Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to fade-out the Gtranslate WP plugin language selection button, called "switcher," from the top of a web page as you scroll down the page.

The following is the plugin's main code:

```html
<div class="switcher notranslate">
  <div class="selected">
    <a href="#" onclick="return false;"><img
        src="//itsabouttime.gallery/wp/wp-content/plugins/gtranslate/flags/32/en-us.png" height="32" width="32"
        alt="en" /> English</a>
  </div>
  <div class="option">
    <a href="#"
      onclick="doGTranslate('en|en');jQuery('div.switcher div.selected a').html(jQuery(this).html());return false;"
      title="English" class="nturl selected"><img
        data-gt-lazy-src="//itsabouttime.gallery/wp/wp-content/plugins/gtranslate/flags/32/en-us.png" height="32"
        width="32" alt="en" /> English</a><a href="#"
      onclick="doGTranslate('en|fr');jQuery('div.switcher div.selected a').html(jQuery(this).html());return false;"
      title="Français" class="nturl"><img
        data-gt-lazy-src="//itsabouttime.gallery/wp/wp-content/plugins/gtranslate/flags/32/fr.png" height="32"
        width="32" alt="fr" /> Français</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  jQuery('.switcher .selected').click(function () { jQuery('.switcher .option a img').each(function () { if (!jQuery(this)[0].hasAttribute('src')) jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('data-gt-lazy-src')) }); if (!(jQuery('.switcher .option').is(':visible'))) { jQuery('.switcher .option').stop(true, true).delay(100).slideDown(500); jQuery('.switcher .selected a').toggleClass('open') } });
  jQuery('.switcher .option').bind('mousewheel', function (e) { var options = jQuery('.switcher .option'); if (options.is(':visible')) options.scrollTop(options.scrollTop() - e.originalEvent.wheelDelta); return false; });
  jQuery('body').not('.switcher').click(function (e) { if (jQuery('.switcher .option').is(':visible') && e.target != jQuery('.switcher .option').get(0)) { jQuery('.switcher .option').stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp(500); jQuery('.switcher .selected a').toggleClass('open') } });
</script>

<style>
  #goog-gt-tt {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .goog-te-banner-frame {
    display: none !important;
  }

  .goog-te-menu-value:hover {
    text-decoration: none !important;
  }

  .goog-text-highlight {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
  }

  body {
    top: 0 !important;
  }

  #google_translate_element2 {
    display: none !important;
  }
</style>

<div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
<script>
  function googleTranslateElementInit2() { new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', autoDisplay: false }, 'google_translate_element2'); }
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>
```

To accomplish this, I'm trying to use the following script to fade-out the language selection button (the "switcher") as you scroll down the page, but I need your help to make it work on [this client's website](https://itsabouttime.gallery/). He wants this effect because the button overlaps other content as you scroll down the page on phones.

```html
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
      $('.switcher').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('.switcher').fadeIn();
    }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `class` names and let CSS do the job of fading.

- Consider `opacity` as you can use `transition` on it to fade values.
- Also `pointer-events` to prevent unwanted clicks while invisible.

You can get values from `window.innerHeight` the viewport height, and `window.scrollY` the scrolled distance to the top, and compare them, so you know when to apply changes (i.e: show switcher just over the home image/screen, then hide it).

I.e.:

```js
let switcher;

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');

  window.addEventListener("scroll", e => {
    // If we are below the home image:
    if (window.scrollY > window.innerHeight) {
      // Add the 'hidden' class if not added yet.
      if (!switcher.classList.contains('hidden')) {
        switcher.classList.add('hidden');
      }
      // Else (we are over the home image):
      // Remove the 'hidden' class if it is still here.
    } else if (switcher.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      switcher.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
  position: relative;
}


/* A div just to visualize the home image*/

.home-image {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 100vh;
}

#switcher {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms ease;
}

#switcher.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}


/* Ignore code below. */

* {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="home-image"></div>
  <button id="switcher">"Switcher"</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very, very much. I already have the "switcher" fading when scrolling down the page. Just one question: How can the distance of when it does fade be entered?

Comment: The `window.innerHeight` makes it for you. But you can hard code it. Let's say you want to fade when you scroll half screen, do `window.innerHeight / 2`, for example, or straight with a fixed number.

Comment: By using `window.innerHeight` you ensure the switcher is visible only over the landing page/screen (the person with the clocks backgound). Below that, it will fade.

Comment: Thank you again so much Leo. I will learn more as I work at it.

Answer (score -1):

Use mCustomScrollbar Js or smooth scrolling js like this.

Below copy that link code and put inside your code after see this is work.

https://essesstile.com/wp-includes/js/SmoothScroll.min.js